# How to use JQuery to select the nth option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML

```
<select onchange="this.form.submit()" name="name">
    <option value="9995101E01#17201044055PM">9995101E01#17201044055PM</option>
    <option value="GRR-Example">GRR-Example</option>
    <option value="admin">admin</option>
    <option value="123w">123w</option>
</select>
```

May I know how I can use JQuery to option with value "admin"?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

```
$('select[name=name] option:eq(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/FSdk2/).

Comment: 2 here will select 3rd option in fact. Right?

Comment: Yes `eq(...)` is zero based so `eq(2)` would be the third option.

Answer (score 12):

Like this:

```
$("select[name='name'] option:eq(2)").attr("selected", "selected");
```

EDIT:

To do what you want in your new edit, that is, select the option that has the value of `admin`:

```
$("select[name='name'] option:contains('admin')").attr("selected", "selected");
```

[See it working](http://jsfiddle.net/JTPDM/1/).

Comment: how can i pass a variable instead? I am trying to achieve $('#id' option:eq(variable_name)").attr("selected", "selected");

Comment: Calling val() on a select list will automatically select the option with that value.

Therefore, this should work:

$("select[name='name']").val('admin');

Comment: I realized that by using this approach "onchange" is not being triggered, anyone knows a way to achieve this?

Comment: anyone needing to trigger "onchange" just add:

$("#myId").trigger('onchange');

Answer (score 9):

I think the `nth-child` pseudo-class is what you're looking for:

```
$('select option:nth-child(3)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd not advice setting value of select by using `.attr('selected', 'selected')`.
It's bad practice. If two options have 'selected' attribute - then what is the value of select?

Here is the simple and easy version that will work:

```
 $('select[name="name"]').val('admin');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/FSdk2/522/)

Answer (score 3):

Just updating in case it helps someone. I had a similar requirement but in my case the dropdown was stored as a JavaScript variable. Also I liked how [Denis Matafonov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2460747/denis-matafonov) suggested to make the option in question selected. So here's the final block of code:

```
var target_dd = $('select[name=name]');
$(target_dd).val($(target_dd).find('option:eq(2)').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select nth option **and** trigger onchange event then:

```
function selectOption(nr) {
    var select = $("select");
    if (select.children().length >= nr) {
        let value = select.find('option:eq(' + nr + ')').val();
        select.val(value).change();
    }
}
```