# How to use Javascript to select the nth option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<select class=fruits">
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Grapes">Grapes</option>
<option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

it by default shows orange in the box but I want Grapes in a box. Please help
Thanks

Comment: you want javascript or jquery

Comment: i want the javascript code

Comment: try this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4222950/how-to-use-jquery-to-select-the-nth-option

Comment: in html: `selected="selected"` on the option of your choice!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-change-an-html-selected-option-using-javascript

Comment: check updated answer both the way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change an HTML selected option using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10911526/how-do-i-change-an-html-selected-option-using-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use jQuery, then do it like this

```
$("select.fruits").val("Grapes");
```

Javascript

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('fruits')[0];
element.value = valueToSelect;
```

Comment: @tidehunter please do accept answer if it works foryou

Comment: There are two pages from the first page if I redirect here it should select grapes automatically. I didn't have the access to the Html page of above code. Please help thank you

Answer (score 4):

For your HTML Dropdown

```
<select class=fruits">
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Grapes">Grapes</option>
<option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

> Using JS You can use **below code** to get desired result

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fruits")[0].selectedIndex = 2 // will select Grapes
```

> Just assign index 0,1..to length of dropdown to get selected value

Answer (score 2):

HTML Code:

```
<select class=fruits">
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Grapes">admin</option>
<option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

javascript:

```
$('.fruits option:eq(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

eq(nth), you can pass index which option you want to select by default. it's start from 0 to n-1.

Comment: didn't have name content in select option only class is there

Comment: you can try this now $('.fruits option:eq(2)').attr('selected', 'selected');

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use the selector `:nth-child()` index starts at 1
2. You can use method `.eq()` index starts at 0

```js
$(".fruits").find('option').eq(0).css('color', 'blue')//index starts at 0 so first option will be blue
$(".fruits").find('option:nth-child(2)').css('color', 'red');//index starts at 1 so second option will be red
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="fruits">
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Grapes">admin</option>
<option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the selectedIndex property:

```js
$('select.fruits').prop('selectedIndex',  2);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="fruits">
<option value="Orange">Orange</option>
<option value="Apple">Apple</option>
<option value="Grapes">Grapes</option>
<option value="Kiwi">Kiwi</option>
</select>
```

The code above will select the third option, since the index starts from 0.

Answer (score 0):

In 2023, without jQuery, the correct snippet is this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fruits").selectedIndex = 2
```